# Copy image to clipboard chrome 70

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, copy, clipboard

I'm developing a feature of copying image. and It doesn't work for me on Chrome 70,
Is this possible?
I think it might be a security limitation.

The clipboard API allows only copying text, the write function is undefined

```js
await navigator.clipboard.write([
      new ClipboardItem({
        [blob.type]: blob
      })
    ])
```

also tried this implementation

```js
function copyElementToClipboard(element) {
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  let range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(typeof element === 'string' ? document.getElementById(elementName) : element);
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  document.execCommand('copy');
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
 }
```

but it doesnt work.

How should I enable and implement this feature?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a problem while creating you blob, instead ? The documentation seems to say it's available since Chrome 66 and they put an image in the exemples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardItem

Comment: yes, because my implementation works on chrome 90